# Open a file without dialog

Tags: c#

with openFileDialog you would select a file and after pressing "OPEN" it would paste the filepath of the selected file (c:\blob\template) into an textbox.

I would like to do automatically select the file c:\blob\template en then put the filepath in the textbox. basically the exact same thing as openfiledialog without a dialog. i have been trying to do this for some time now. can somebody help me out with this? i have no clue how to realise this.

i`m only able to get the filepath and paste the string in the textbox but this but only fills the box with a string. i need to load the file/template in there.

```
  private void txt()
    {
        string fileName = "template";
        string fullPath;           
        fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
        lblFirstTemplate.Text = fullPath;

    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having.

Comment: Have you looked at the FileInfo class? It's a standard .net library for accessing file information.

Answer (score 2):

The code you now have will only get the file path. What you need to add is code that will actually open the file and read its content.

Let's say your file contains some text. You can use the following line to read the complete file as text:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
```

If your file contains some other data like binary data, you can use:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
```

And instead of reading all data at once, you can read it one line or a couple of bytes at a time. A good place in the documentation to start is: [Common I/O Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, this did help. but i still have one question left. 

when i am using a open filedialog i use this code to get a string containing the file. and put it in a textbox:

     string piclocation = dlg.FileName.ToString();   
     textBox1.Text = piclocation; 

where filename gets or sets a string containing the file. how do i get this without using a dialog?

Comment: If the user doesn't explicitly choose a file through the dialog, you need to already know the file name upfront. If you want to let the user choose a file, the dialog is your best solution.